# checkstyle-checker.xml keeps on being overriden by a default file

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I created a simple initial `my-checks.xml` file in my base directory, which can be validated and used by intelliJ:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <!--
        If you set the basedir property below, then all reported file
        names will be relative to the specified directory. See
        http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/5.x/config.html#Checker

        <property name="basedir" value="${basedir}"/>
    -->

    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>


    <module name="TreeWalker">

        <module name="NeedBraces"/>

    </module>

</module>
```

In my pom.xml that is in the base dir I have the following:

```
<build>
..
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>my-checks.xml</configLocation>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
..
</build>
```

Now I can run `mvn clean install` and have the `checkstyle-checker.xml` generated in the `target` folder. This file will be identical to `my-checks.xml`. Great! So far so good!!

Now I run `mvn checkstyle:check`...
It seems that `checkstyle-checker.xml` is swapped by `sun-checks.xml` when the goal is ran!!!

How can I use my own configuration???

Comment: By the way Intellij marks the linkXRef tag in red and says that it is "not allowed here"
I think this is a problem only with intellj though, but not sure so I am mentioning it.

Comment: Apparently I can do:
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.config.location=[path to my checkstyle file]
But this is retarded!! I expect that the config in the pom to suffice

Answer (score 1):

Within my maven project I use the following successfully:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
      <checkstyleXmlOutput>true</checkstyleXmlOutput>
      <checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>target/site</checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>
      <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
      <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

So my `configuration` is outside the `executions` section.